# Install PHP Extension xml

Tags: php, xml, debian

I installed phpmyadmin but when I go to myIP/phpmyadmin, I get this error:

`Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: xml`

I have tried to reinstall it but nothing changed

Maybe still important when I reinstall it, I get this output:
`php8.0-xml is already the newest version (8.0.12-1+0~20211022.25+debian10~1.gbp06192c).`

Comment: Already tried to restart your webserver? Maybe this is a better question for superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you do check your PHP version with `phpinfo();`?

Maybe you have more than one PHP version installed on your system and you are installing the XML in a different PHP installation.